# How to delete the first column in every sheet in a workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 10+ sheets, and I need to delete the first column in every sheet.
Instead of manually doing this, I was wondering if anyone knew a short VBA macro that could do this for me?
Thanks!

Comment: Select the first sheet, Shift+click on the last sheet tab - delete the first column.

Comment: I know you already have an answer, but what I normally do is just record a macro of what I want to do. Then modify it for what I need to do (i.e. looping over all worksheets). Some things seem confusing or daunting until you record the macro and realize it isn't actually that hard. It also helps you teach yourself a little more.

Comment: @Constuntine Great thanks! I will try the recording method as well- might make the more complicated macros easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop over all the worksheets:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want ws.Range("A:A")